# any Crystal Reports training videos out there?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm starting to look at reporting tools for use with my projects. For economic reasons, Crystal Reports (the version included with VS2008) will be my "choice." I've been told this is not the best reporting tool out there but it's what I have right now.

Are there any *free* training videos for Crystal Reports? I found the "How Do I..." video series on the MSDN Developer Center site and www.asp.net but nothing on Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't viewed many of these, but believe it or not youtube has a lot of Crystal Reports related videos. Since anyone can submit anything I wouldn't take what everyone says as the gospel without seeing some credentials to prove that they know what they are talking about, but at worst case you can see some demonstrations of Crystal in use.

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=crystal+reports